# Is using the genitive case recursively a correct usage?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

I wanted to write about a farmer who has children with very strange toys. Thus, I wrote:

> The farmer's children's toys were quite strange.

**Would that be correct?** I could not find examples to whether this usage was correct or not so I assumed it could be, albeit uncommon.

If I understand correctly, an equivalent phrase should be:

> The toys of the farmer's children were quite strange.

Comment: It's grammatical either way, but after a few catenations, it becomes quite a choo-choo train.

Comment: It's actually not that uncommon to see this kind of thing in English, but it can get confusing. I would never put more than two possessives in a row like this.

Comment: I would do it rarely.  For example, "your children, and your children's children, and your children's children's children" is a sometimes-seen phrase.

Comment: Technically yes, but avoid it whenever possible. It's weak and ambiguous writing, and just sounds awkward written on paper in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct, but have different strengths. The first is more conversational and sounds somewhat more natural, but it's ambiguous. The second phrase is clear, but sounds a little dry.

Specifically, the phrase "Farmer's children's toys" can be interpreted 2 ways. The first is "the *farmer's children's* toys", as in the toys of the farmer's children.
The second is "the farmer's *children's toys*", as in children's toys owned by the farmer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but avoid it whenever possible. It's weak and ambiguous writing, and just sounds awkward written on paper in general.

In a situation like this, there's always a better way to write the sentence:

> The farmer's children had quite strange toys.
>
> His children's toys were quite strange. (if it's obvious that "he" refers to the farmer)
>
> Their toys were quite strange. (same as above, except with "they" and the children)